# Declare an Instance Variable to Reference an Object

Tags: java, object, instance-variables, japplet

So we are making an Avatar for a game and we have already created the Avatar as an `Avatar` class file. Our problem is that in our class file `Game` we are having difficulty declaring Avatar as an instance variable. 
The code is as follows:

```
public class Game extends JApplet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final long WIDTH = 800;
    public static final long HEIGHT = 600;

    // Declare an instance variable to reference your Avatar object

    public @Override void init() {
        // Store an instantiated Avatar into the instance variable
        setSize(new Dimension( WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE); 
    }

    public @Override void paint(Graphics g) { 
        super.paint(g); // Call the JAplet paint method (inheritance)
        // Call the draw method in your Avatar class
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you followed the Tutorial path on Oracle's site?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: And what, exactly, is stopping you from declaring an instance variable for the Avatar?  Sorry, I really can't see what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
private Avatar avatar;

avatar = new Avatar();

avatar.draw();
```

Like this:

```
public class Game extends JApplet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public static final long WIDTH = 800;
public static final long HEIGHT = 600;

// Declare an instance variable to reference your Avatar object
private Avatar avatar;


public @Override void init() {
    // Store an instantiated Avatar into the instance variable
    avatar = new Avatar();

    setSize(new Dimension( WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE); 
}

public @Override void paint(Graphics g) { 
    super.paint(g); // Call the JAplet paint method (inheritance)
    // Call the draw method in your Avatar class

    avatar.draw(); //replace "draw" with method you want to invoke :)
    }
}
```